# Gtk::Builder fails and immediately aborts when reading a file?

Tags: windows, gtkmm, gtkbuilder

I'm trying to load a very basic Glade file from the same directory. However, Gtk::Builder always fails and aborts with

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Gtk::BuilderError'
```

even though I surrounded everything in a try statement.

Just for clarity, the source is at http://pastebin.com/hRBuAi2d, and the glade file at http://pastebin.com/c9ZvgbWi.

Is the Gtkmm I have broken? That's the only reasoning I can come up with.

Comment: Please post the code here the next time you post a question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `id="window1"` to `id="mainwindow"` in your ui file, it ran fine here.

You are trying to `ref_builder->get_widget('mainwindow', win)` where your window is actually called "window1" in the ui file.

Edit: though I am on Linux x64, not windows.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have missed that.